# Statistical analysis, what test should I use?

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test

I have categorical data collected from a questionnaire.

It's mainly (Yes/No/Don't know) answers with the exception of the name of the software.

I'm doing a security analysis on different kinds of software, so the questions are basically 'Does your software use this security measure?'

I'm having a hard time finding out what statistical analysis I should use, and would love some input.

I'm guessing my independent variable is in this case the name of the software gathered from the questionnaire, and the dependent variable is the question itself (Does your software use ....).

Some of the softwares are used more often than others, so for some of the softwares the amount of answers is below 5. Does that rule out the Chi-Square test? Should I go for Fishers exact test instead?

My goal later on is to present a comparison between the softwares saying 'this software is more secure than that software'

***Example data from one software***

[image: Example]

All the best!

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of your data?

Comment: I find it pointless to rate the security of different software products based on the survey results asking people `Does you SW have feature X?`. Can't you look at the software and determine it yourself? You can ask people what software they use, and gather statistics about that. But doesn't the name of the software (together with version) determine the features?

Comment: Thanks for showing interest! Added some data! Some of the softwares are in house developed, and hard to get access to, and almost no information to be gathered about them online. Thats why I went with a survey.